# How can I use python and its packages to extract specific data from thousands of pdfs

Tags: python, pdf, web-crawler

I have downloaded more than 2000 pdfs which are anual reports of companies .I want to extract specific data from the forms of pdf, such as the loans.I have tried pdfMiner and pypdf, but they didn't seem to work well, is there any other ways using programming?

Comment: *I want to extract specific data from the forms of pdf, such as the loans*. Not informative at all. Please post an example of such pdf

Comment: In short, I need to extract some tables in the pdf without ruinning their formats like importing them to excel or stata. THX!
@YannisP.

Comment: One option would be to use Tabula [http://tabula.technology/]. Otherwise Apache Tika can export the pdf to html or xml  and from there you can try different hacks